# Being/ becoming a graduate

Tags: word-choice

> What do you want to do **after being** a graduate ?

Or

> What do you want to do **after becoming**  a  graduate ?

Which one amongst the above 2 sentences is correct ?

Comment: Being a graduate or becoming a graduate ?!?

Comment: We wouldn't usually say "after becoming a graduate" or "after being a graduate", we would just say "after graduating".

Comment: @SubratBavarianBastola  I see you've edited your question, in which case it's a moot point.  "To graduate" is a verb, and needs no other to explain the transition from *student* to *not student*.  **"What you do you plan to do after you *graduate*?"**

Comment: And could you kindly explain me the difference between -what are your plans  after graduating ? And what are your plans after you graduate?

Comment: Subrat, if you have a different question, you should ask it as a separate question. You may want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works, it's a bit different from other Internet forums.

Comment: What @stangdon said. Strictly speaking, the *second* of OP's two alternatives is "more natural", but since in practice *neither* would be at all likely, I think they'd both have much the same effect to a native speaker audience (we'd try to think of some quirky specific nuance that the speaker might have wished to convey, if he were known to be a native speaker himself; if not, we'd just register it as a minor "failure of idiomacy" from a non-native speaker).

Answer (score 1):

Once you graduate, you spend the rest of your life **being a graduate**. In the process of graduating, you **become a graduate**. *To be* a graduate is a matter of state; *to become* a graduate is a matter of changing that state.

Thus, *after being a graduate* doesn't make a great deal of sense, though people will know what you mean if you say it. *After becoming a graduate* means *after you have graduated*. You can also use the progressive form of the verb *to graduate*, rather than using *becoming* - you can say *after graduating* instead.